# Left join tables in a while loop and dynamically name the new table which is again used in left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @i int
declare @next varchar(10)
declare @same varchar(10)

set @i=1

while (@i<3)
begin 
set @next = cast(@i+1 as varchar(10))
set @same = cast(@i as varchar(10))

declare @temp nvarchar(max)
set @temp = 'select A.*,
             B.col1 as LVL_'+@next+
            'into loop_'+@next
             from (select * from loop_'+@same'+) A
             left join (select col1, col2 where col1 is not null) B
             on A.LVL'+@same+'=B.col1'

execute sp_executesql @temp
end;
```

It shows message error as
incorrect syntax near 'loop_2'
incorrect syntax near 'A.'
incorrect syntax near 'B.'

Comment: It's missing a comma after A.*

Comment: Your code has a lot of incorrect synatx errors. For example `decalre`

Comment: Develop good habits. Stop cramming all your code together for many reasons; use white space to make your code readable. More readable = less prone to error = easier to debug. And if you attempt dynamic sql, you will need to SEE IT to debug it.

Comment: after all the changes shows same error message

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment @i too.  Also, if you want to see the output use `Print`.

```
DECLARE @i INT;
DECLARE @next VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @same VARCHAR(10);

SET @i = 1;

WHILE (@i < 3)
BEGIN
    SET @next = CAST(@i + 1 AS VARCHAR(10));
    SET @same = CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(10));

    DECLARE @temp NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @temp
        = N'select A.*,
             B.col1 as LVL_' + @next + N'into loop_' + @next + N'
             from (select * from loop_' + @same
          + N') A
             left join (select col1, col2 where col1 is not null) B
             on A.LVL' + @same + N'=B.col1';

    SET @i = @i+1
    -- print @temp
    execute sp_executesql @temp
END;
```